# Set ConnectionId for SignalR in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Due to a migration from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 8, we had to switch
the SignalR implementation in our frontend.

We used the `ConnectionId` in internal processes. In the "old" version (ASP.NET Framework 4.8), it was guaranteed to be a GUID. With .NET Core onwards, it is "just" a
string.

Is there a way to configure how to generate IDs for Clients in .NET (ASP.NET 8)?
So for example a way to configure the `Hub` to allow a custom Id generator.

Comment: Nope, no customization.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13443

Comment: That is very unfortunate. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to configure how to generate IDs for Clients in .NET
> (ASP.NET 8)? So for example a way to configure the Hub to allow a
> custom Id generator.

Accoording to your scenario, let me explain a importnat point, In `ASP.NET Core SignalR`, the ConnectionId is indeed represented as a string, and by default, it is a unique identifier generated by SignalR for each connection.
However, SignalR itself does not provide a direct way to customize the generation of connection IDs out of the box.

At of now it's not supported because, SignalR in ASP.NET Core prioritizes flexibility, performance, and security over strict GUID-based ConnectionIds. This decision balances scalability in high-traffic scenarios, potential transport optimizations, security concerns, and the ability to tailor ID generation to specific application needs.

Thus, SignalR aims to be more lightweight and efficient than its ASP.NET Framework counterpart. Requiring GUID-based ConnectionIds would introduce a dependency on the System.Guid type, which might not be necessary for all use cases.

**Note:** As its directly not supported, so you can check this [github thread](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13443) which might be resourceful for you.